# "(time zone)" acceptable input to new Date() on some machines, but others expect "time zone"

Tags: javascript, regex, date, operating-system

We have a function that parses a date/time pair in UTC as JS does, but then forces it to behave as if it was specified in the local timezone. Below:

```
var tz = (new Date()).toString().match(/\((.+)\)$/)[0];
var str = (new Date()).toUTCString();
str = str.replace(/GMT$/,tz);
var output = new Date(str);
```

The regex returns two results, for my timezone I get `'(Pacific Daylight Time)'` and `'Pacific Daylight Time'`. For all our macs and ubuntu machines, `'Pacific Daylight Time'` or  `var tz = (new Date()).toString().match(/\((.+)\)$/)[1];` works. However, on some of our windows machines, regardless of the browser, we require `'(Pacific Daylight Time)'` or `var tz = (new Date()).toString().match(/\((.+)\)$/)[0];` , or `new Date(str)` evaluates to `Invalid Date`.

What is causing this? Is it really some weird OS difference? How can we check for this?

[Here's a repl](https://repl.it/CZkl/0) where I've been playing around on it with different machines, etc.

Comment: FYI `(new Date()).toString() === Date()`

Comment: Can't you just use the full match `.match(/\(.*?\)/)[0]`

Comment: @andlrc if I throw the result into a replace, and then new Date(str) as above using the full match, which returns for me `'(Pacific Daylight Time)'`, I get "Invalid Date" on my machine, but not on others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is causing this?

The output of [*Date.prototype.toString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.tostring) is **entirely** implementation dependent.

> Is it really some weird OS difference?

It's been that way from the beginning and is consistent with the specification (see above).

> How can we check for this?

There is no standard for naming time zones, and you can't rely on implementations consistently naming them either. Different implementations use different names.

E.g. the *toString* method in Chrome reports "E. Australia Standard Time" and IE shows "UTC+1000" for the time zone commonly known as "Australian Eastern Standard Time".

The time zone offset for the host is returned by *Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset* in minutes, but has an opposite sign to the ISO 8601 convention. So +10:00 is -600, -07:00 is +420.

From your comment on andlrc's answer:

> but it's coming in like date = 2016-06-12 and time = 11:45:00 , which
>   are then set to str as str = (new Date(date + "T" +
>   time))toUTCString();

That is a peculiar thing to do. A date and time with no time zone will be treated as local, so will be adjusted for the local time zone. You then output it in GMT time zone, so it will show a different date and time depending on the host system's time zone setting.

Also, parsing strings with the Date constructor (or Date.parse) is strongly recommended against as it is inconsistent across browsers (your parsing above will return an invalid date in IE 8, some hosts will allow out of range values and some won't). You should manually parse the date and time (a library can help, but a parsing function for a particular format is very simple to write).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you are over complication things, can't you simply use:

```
new Date(Date.now() + (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
```

Or for better compatibility and avoiding multiply date objects:

```
var a = new Date();
a.setTime(a.getTime() + a.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: I think this makes a lot more sense, I'm testing it out right now and will reply when I've grocked this (dates are hard!). I don't have the other half of this equation (where the input is coming from) but it's coming in like `date = 2016-06-12` and `time =  11:45:00` , which are then set to str as `str = (new Date(date + "T" + time))toUTCString();`